# Kendo Numeric text box for GBP Currency in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, currency-formatting, kendonumerictextbox

I was working with kendo numeric text box with currency format. As the below code which you provided in the sample data. It was working fine with the ISOCode of USD and EUR. I was trying to get the currency symbol for GBP '£', i'm failing to get the currency symbol. Can you please get back to me whether i was missing some thing in the code or is the ability for this pound symbol is not included? I have even checked in the sample you provided, it's not binding the value over there.

```
<kendo-numerictextbox
        [format]="formatOptions"
        [value]="value"
        [min]="0"
    ></kendo-numerictextbox>



public formatOptions: any = {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'GBP',
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol'
};
```

Comment: They don't have all Currency loaded, you need to download the Locale for what you need. Check this: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/globalization/internationalization/loading-data/